# How to read one row at a time from excel file using aspose in java

Tags: java, aspose-cells

I have an excel file with 1000's of rows and I want read each row at a time in Java using aspose API's. I want to convert each row into a `String` array. Can anyone help me with this?

```
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
Cells cells = worksheet.getCells();
```

Comment: It's no answering your question, but it is not too complicated with poi (free), did much more difficult stuff with it (https://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: I have done it POI, I want to use aspose now.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Cells provides the LightCells API, mainly designed to read/ write  cell's data one by one without building a complete data model block (using the Cell collection etc.) into memory. It works in an event-driven mode. I think you may try it. When reading template files, the component parses every cell and provides their value one by one.  Please see the document for your reference [here](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Using+LightCells+API).

I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells cells = worksheet.getCells();
Range range = cells.getMaxDisplayRange();
int totalColumns = range.getColumnCount();
int totalRows = range.getRowCount();
RowCollection rows = cells.getRows();

for (int i = 1; i < rows.getCount(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++) {
        System.out.print(cells.get(i, j).getValue() + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.